# Error C2228 using API

Tags: c++, class, winapi

I'm making Othello game.
Nearly all is coded, and i need to run the program.
But, there's error C2228.
I don't know why this error has been occured.
At my code, which line is problem?

This is API code.

```
#include "Basic.h"
#include "Othello.h"
#include "resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND , UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM ) ;
HINSTANCE g_hInst ;
LPCWSTR lpszClass = TEXT ( "First" ) ;

//Tile tile () ;

int APIENTRY WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance , HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
                      , LPSTR lpszCmdParam , int nCmdShow )
{
    HWND hWnd ;
    MSG Message ;
    WNDCLASS WndClass ;
    g_hInst = hInstance ;

    WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
    WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0 ;
    WndClass.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH ) GetStockObject ( WHITE_BRUSH ) ;
    WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor ( NULL , IDC_ARROW ) ;
    WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon ( NULL , IDI_APPLICATION ) ;
    WndClass.hInstance = hInstance ;
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc = ( WNDPROC)WndProc ;
    WndClass.lpszClassName = lpszClass ;
    WndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
    WndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
    RegisterClass ( &WndClass ) ;

    hWnd = CreateWindow ( lpszClass , lpszClass , WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ,
        CW_USEDEFAULT , CW_USEDEFAULT , CW_USEDEFAULT , CW_USEDEFAULT ,
        NULL , ( HMENU ) NULL , hInstance , NULL ) ;
    ShowWindow ( hWnd , nCmdShow ) ;

    while ( GetMessage ( &Message , 0 , 0 , 0 ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage ( &Message ) ;
        DispatchMessage ( &Message ) ;
    }
    return Message.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND hWnd , UINT iMessage , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam )
{
    HDC hdc , hMemdc [ 3 ] ;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
    HBITMAP hEmpty , hBlack , hGray ;
    BITMAP bit ;
    Tile tile () ;

    switch(iMessage)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
        break ;

    case WM_PAINT :

        hdc = BeginPaint ( hWnd , &ps ) ;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i )
        {
            hMemdc [ i ] = CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc ) ;
        }

        hEmpty = LoadBitmap ( g_hInst , MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_BITMAP1 ) ) ;
        hBlack = LoadBitmap ( g_hInst , MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_BITMAP2 ) ) ;
        hGray = LoadBitmap ( g_hInst , MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_BITMAP3 ) ) ;

        SelectObject ( hMemdc [ 0 ] , hEmpty ) ;
        SelectObject ( hMemdc [ 1 ] , hBlack ) ;
        SelectObject ( hMemdc [ 2 ] , hGray ) ;

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; ++j )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
            {
                BitBlt ( hdc , 50 * i , 50 * j , 50 , 50 , hMemdc [ tile . iTileinfo ( i , j ) ] , 0 , 0 , SRCCOPY ) ;
            }
        }

        BitBlt ( hdc , 550 , 250 , 50 , 50 , hMemdc [ 2 - ( tile . bTurninfo () ) ] , 0 , 0 , SRCCOPY ) ;

        DeleteObject ( hEmpty ) ;
        DeleteDC ( hMemdc [ 0 ] ) ;
        DeleteObject ( hBlack ) ;
        DeleteDC ( hMemdc [ 1 ] ) ;
        DeleteObject ( hGray ) ;
        DeleteDC ( hMemdc [ 2 ] ) ;

        EndPaint ( hWnd , &ps ) ;

        break ;

    case WM_DESTROY :
        PostQuitMessage ( 0 ) ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    return ( DefWindowProc ( hWnd , iMessage , wParam , lParam ) ) ;
}
```

And this is class code.

```
#include "Othello.h"

Tile :: Tile ()
{
    aryRemover = new Remover [ 8 ] ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
    {
        aryRemover [ i ] . iDirection = 0 ;
        aryRemover [ i ] . iNum = 0 ;
    }

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; ++j )
        {
            iAry [ i ] [ j ] = 0 ;
        }
    }

    iAry [ 4 ] [ 4 ] = 1 ;
    iAry [ 4 ] [ 5 ] = 2 ;
    iAry [ 5 ] [ 4 ] = 2 ;
    iAry [ 5 ] [ 5 ] = 1 ;

    bTurn = false ;
    iCount = 0 ;
}

Tile :: ~ Tile ()
{
    delete [] aryRemover ;
}

void Tile :: Possible ( int iX , int iY )
{
    if ( bTurn ) // Player 1
    {
    long code
    }

    else // Player 2
    {
    long code
    }
}

void Tile :: Change ( int iX , int iY )
{
    if ( bTurn ) // Player 1
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < iCount ; ++i )
        {
            switch ( aryRemover [ i ] . iDirection )
            {
            case 0 :
                long code
            default :
                break ;
            }

        }

        bTurn = false ; // Turn Player 2
        iCount = 0 ;
    }

    else // Player 2
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < iCount ; ++i )
        {
            switch ( aryRemover [ i ] . iDirection )
            {
            case 0 :
                long code
            default :
                break ;
            }
        }

        bTurn = true ; // Turn Player 1
        iCount = 0 ;
    }
}

int Tile :: iTileinfo ( int iX , int iY )
{
    return iAry [ iX ] [ iY ] ;
}

bool Tile :: bTurninfo ()
{
    if ( bTurn )
        return true ;
    else
        return false ;
}

void Tile :: Routine ( int iX , int iY )
{
    Tile :: Possible ( iX , iY ) ;
    Tile :: Change ( iX , iY ) ;
}
```

and error.

> error C2228: left of '.bTurninfo' must have class/struct/union.
>
> error C2228: left of '.iTileinfo' must have class/struct/union.

Problem's code is in API code.

At `WM_PAINT` Section, code using `Bitblt` function.

I wait for your answer.
Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tile tile () ;
```

declares a function tile().

You want

```
Tile tile;
```

which creates a tile object

Comment: Then tile object can't access to protected member.

Comment: @Rica Those member should probably be public.

Comment: @Rica Please stay on topic. The class declaration cannot be seen and there is no mention of protected members in the question. You asked about a compiler error and this is the answer.